# Mail add-in sent event

Tags: outlook, add-in, office365

Is there a way to perform one final action right before an email is sent.  I am making a Mail Add-in and I want to notify my application when the user sends the email.  I am looking for a final state that let's my application know the user is finished composing their email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the COM addins, you can use Application.ItemSend event. For the web based addins, there is no such callback.

Comment: That's what I figured, just wanted to see if anyone had found some ways.  Thanks for your help!